# How do I make the grid row clickable in css

Tags: html, css, grid

I have a grid setup with 1 row and 4 columns.  The row is 85% width. I'd like the entire row to change color on hover and be clickable to access another page..

With my current setup, the row changes colors and is clickable, however, the link is active outside of the 85% width, meaning if the user clicks to the left or right of the row, the link is still active.  I would like the link only active when clicking on the actual row.

```
/* CSS CODE */
.ListWrapper {
    display:grid;
    grid-template-columns:1.5fr 1.8fr 1.5fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows:1fr;
    grid-template-areas: "ListTitleTxt email phone groups";
    background-color:#EDF5FC;
    cursor:pointer;
    margin:auto;
    width:85% }

.ListWrapper:hover { background-color:#1b9bff; color:white; }

.BlackLink:link { text-decoration:none; color:black; }

/* HTML CODE */
<a class='BlackLink' href='#'>
<div class='ListWrapper'>
    <div class='ListTitleTxt'>name</div>
    <div class='email'>email</div>
    <div class='phone'>phone</div>
    <div class='groups'>groups</div></div>
</div></a>
```

Comment: can you post [mcve]?

Comment: Thank you, I simplified the code into a minimal reproducible example

Comment: grid and and negative margin on a link could do something close to what you need. You need to know the height of your line to adapt the size of the link . https://jsfiddle.net/2gq4kd5a/ A bit tricky but avoids absolute position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by adding an additional div before the a tag with the 85% width, and then changing the width of the ListWrapper to 100%..

[JSfiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/40gnh53w/)

```
.ListLink { width:80%; margin:auto; }
.ListLink:hover { background-color:#1b9bff; color:white; }

.ListWrapper {
    display:grid;
    grid-template-columns:1.5fr 1.8fr 1.5fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows:1fr;
    grid-template-areas: "ListTitleTxt email phone groups";
    background-color:#EDF5FC;
    cursor:pointer;
    margin:auto;
    width:100% }

.ListWrapper:hover { background-color:#1b9bff; color:white; }
.BlackLink:link { text-decoration:none; color:black; }

<div class='ListLink'>
<a href='#' class='BlackLink'>
<div class='ListWrapper'>
    <div class='ListTitleTxt'>name</div>
    <div class='email'>email</div>
    <div class='phone'>phone</div>
    <div class='groups'>groups</div>
</div></a>
</div>
```